# $\lim_{x\to +\infty} \ln (1+x) \cdot \sin (\frac{1}{\ln(2x-1)}) $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have to solve the limit
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \ln (1+x) \cdot \sin \left(\frac{1}{\ln(2x-1)}\right)  $$

applying Taylor's series.
I can change the variable:
$$\lim_{y\to o^{+}} \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right) \cdot \sin \left(\frac{1}{\ln(2\frac{1}{y}-1)}\right) =  \lim_{y\to o^{+}} \ln \left(\frac{y+1}{y}\right) \cdot \sin \left(\frac{1}{\ln(\frac{2-y}{y})}\right) =  \lim_{y\to 0^{+}} (\ln (y+1)-\ln y) \cdot \sin \left(\frac{1}{\ln (2-y) - \ln y}\right) $$

But I have problems with the taylor's series of $\ln x $ in $0$

Then I tried with:
$$\ln (1+x) \cdot \sin \left(\frac{1}{\ln(2x-1)}\right) \sim 
  \ln (1+x) \cdot \frac{1}{\ln(2x-1)}= \ln (1+\tfrac{1}{y}) \cdot \frac{1}{\ln(2\frac{1}{y}-1)}= \frac{\ln (1+\frac{1}{y})}{\ln (\frac{2}{y}-1)} =  \frac{\ln(y+1)- \ln y}{\ln(2-y)- \ln y} \sim   \frac{- \ln y}{\ln(2)- \ln y}  \sim 1 $$

and it is indeed  the suggested solution in my book. But I haven't applied taylor's series.
Can someone give some hint how to procede with the other method?

Comment: 0<sin(1/ln(2x-1))<1/ln(x)

Comment: The Taylor series at $y = 0$ doesn't exist, as the derivative diverges to $-\infty$ near $y = 0$.

Comment: but is it right if I change the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what your exercise meant is : do a Taylor series expansion, up to the first order, of $t\to \sin(t)$. You directly wrote an equivalent, which of course amounts to the same, since $\sin 0=0$.
But if you want to be very Taylor series compliant, you can choose as a variable $y=\ln(2x-1)^{-1}$. Then $y\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$.

$$
\ln (x+1) = \ln ( \frac12 \left( 2x -1 +1\right) +1 ) = \ln\left( \frac{\left( 2x -1\right) +3}{2}\right)
$$
which becomes
$$
\ln (x+1) = \frac1y -\ln(2) + \ln \left( 1+ 3 \exp\left(-\frac1y\right) \right). 
$$
And your problem is
$$
\left(\frac1y -\ln(2) + \ln \left( 1+ 3 \exp\left(-\frac1y\right) \right)\right)\sin y
$$
as $y\to0$. Then an expansion of $\sin y=0+y+o(y)$...and surprise, surprise, the result you already found appears.